# What does 'broadly conceived' mean?

Tags: meaning

> The course is very broadly conceived (= it covers a wide range of topics)

According to Oxford dictionary, 'conceive' means 'to form a plan or idea in mind'. Why does 'broadly conceived' means 'to cover a wide range of sth' in the sentence above? Is the course still thought of in mind or has it become an existing thing in reality?

Answer (score 2):

The [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/conceive) definition perhaps leads most clearly to understanding this fixed expression ('broadly conceived'):

> **conceive** [verb]
> 1 [intransitive, transitive] [formal] *to imagine a particular situation or to think about something in a particular way*

So 'broadly conceived' is seen as applying to, in the first instance, an idea or field where boundaries aren't too rigorously defined

> - *Also that year, he received the Japan Art Association's Praemium Imperiale prize* *for "painting" (broadly conceived)*. [[Encyclopedia
>   Britannica; Ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/broadly+conceived)]

One wonders what 'his' entry actually was. Note that 'broadly speaking' is a common variant for the comment on precision in the use of language.

However, the string has broadened to overlap with the 'create' sense of 'conceive', so that one might see say

> - *All three works on the program were broadly conceived, spreading their wings to take in the full range of a symphony orchestra's tones*
>   *and timbres*. [[The New York Times - Arts;
>   Ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/broadly+conceived)]

with the meaning 'diverse', 'composed so as to have many elements'. Here, note that 'is/are/was/were broadly conceived' uses the auxiliary *be*, and is arguably more verbal (a passive construction) in nature.

Comment: What are those 'boundaries' that aren't too rigorously defined? How do you deduce that 'broadly conceived' can apply to those whose 'boundaries aren't too rigorously defined' from the Longman dictionary definition?

Comment: (1) That depends, of course, on the field etc involved. In the example, "painting" might have been extended to allow collages, even photoshopped images.  (2) 'Broadly conceived' in the sense first mentioned above obviously means 'loosely defined'. Cognitive functions are often conflated semantically.

Comment: @Dat Nguyen To put it simpler, "painting" is conceived in a broad sense. In your pattern "to conceive" means "to devise, form, think out", i.e. "The [idea, conception of] course has been (is) devised/formed/thought out so that it can cover a very wide range of topics".